# Discord.py: how do i make the bot get a list of users who reacted to a message in a given time

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

i am making a discord.py bot on python 3.8.6.

i want this particular function to work in the specific way...

- the bot sends a embed `message = await ctx.send(embed=e)`
- the bot will add a react to the embed `await message.add_reaction('✅')`
- the bot will wait for 30 seconds for other users to react and make a list of who ever reacts within 30 seconds
- proceed with further commands

code-

```py
@bot.command()
async def command_name(ctx, function):


    #code for function 1

    #code for function 2

        # making the embed

        message = await ctx.send(embed=e)
        await message.add_reaction('✅')

        def check(reaction, user):
            if user not in players and not user.bot:
                players.append(user.mention)
            return reaction.message == message and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'

        try:
            await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10, check=check)

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('time is up, and not enough players')

        else:
            await ctx.send(players) 
            # further code
```

issue: the bot instantly sends the list players

question: what can i add for it to wait 30 seconds, append the list with users who react to the embed and then send the list and if after 30 seconds len(players) isn't 3 or more send -

`await ctx.send('time is up, and not enough players')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10, check=check)` proceeds at the first reaction made. In this case, the bot reaction instantly triggers this event, so an empty list will be returned.

I thought of two options:

1. Make the check function always return False, but still append the user. This way the wait_for function will stay active until the timeout and then raise an Exception. Continue your code in the except block or pass it.
2. Wait 30 seconds, then fetch the message again and append all users who have reacted with the checkmark.

First option:

```
@client.command()
async def command_name(ctx):

    players = []

    message = await ctx.send("Message")
    await message.add_reaction('✅')

    def check(reaction, user):
        if user not in players and not user.bot:
            players.append(user.mention)
        return False

    try:
        await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30, check=check)

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass

    if len(players) < 3:
        await ctx.send('Time is up, and not enough players')
    else:
        await ctx.send(players)
```

Second (preferred) option:

```
@client.command()
async def command_name(ctx):

    players = []

    message = await ctx.send("Message")
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await asyncio.sleep(30)

    message = await ctx.fetch_message(message.id)

    for reaction in message.reactions:
        if reaction.emoji == '✅':
            async for user in reaction.users():
                if user != client.user:
                    players.append(user.mention)

    if len(players) < 3:
        await ctx.send('Time is up, and not enough players')
    else:
        await ctx.send(players)
```

References to the [API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html):
[fetch_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)
[reaction.users()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction.users)